# org mode, collect today's tasks into a buffer and edit them

Tags: org-mode

In short, is there a agenda-like view that is also editable (without going to the original org file)

For instance, I'd like to create a view which shows all the todo items which have deadline today. (which are possibly collected from multiple agenda files).
This can be done in agenda view (or using some query such as org-ql).

Additionally, I also want to be able to edit the view as if I'm working on a regular org file.
and I want to make those edits appear in the original org file.

Below is the strategy I'd implement if I have to do it myself.

```
- Assign `ID` to todo headings when creating them.
- `collect-todo-for-today`
  - scans agenda files and copies the wanted todo items (eg, deadline today) and create a buffer
  - the copied item has it's own `ID` (child-id) and has `parent-id`
  - the original item create property `CHILD_IDS` and appends child-id to the list
- `refile-back-to-parent` (on the copied item) copies the edited child to the parent (possibly merge them)
  - if refile-back is successful: parent's content is updated and `CHILD_IDS` updated, child item gets deleted
```

(Having copies makes syncing a problem, so I expect them not problem free, and the syncing doesn't have to be automatic)

I'm relatively new to org mode, and not sure if what I want is already doable or it's already implemented somewhere

Comment: FYI, org-agenda support basic edit through `M-x org-agenda-bulk-action`, or you may take a look at `org-agenda-follow-mode`.

Comment: The agenda provides so-called "remote editing" commands (see [Commands in the agenda buffer](https://orgmode.org/manual/Agenda-Commands.html) in the manual). As @shynur points out, you can mark mutliple items in the agenda and execute a remote command on all of the items. You can also define your own remote commands if the built-in ones are insufficient. For ad-hoc changes, you can use `TAB` on an item to visit the item in the file, make changes and then jump back to the agenda and refresh it (with `g`). That is *much* simpler than copying and syncing.

Comment: I consider the "without going to the original org file" requirement completely wrong-headed and leading you into thickets of unnecessary and unwelcome complexity. If you have a need that is not met by the methods above, please modify the question and add a detailed case which illustrates that need.

Comment: i want org agenda to be editable without moving buffers. it's simple
And if org agenda doesn't allow it, i ask if there's other way. 

I want my tasks structured according to category, 
and at the same time, I want my tasks according to timeline (which agenda provides) , and i want to edit in both modes..